# C# - AES decryption is too slow

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

The below function is decrypting large photos (4-20 MB). The main problem is the performance; It can take up to 18 seconds to decrypt one photo.

Just to clarify, I'm using end-to-end encryption, and photos have to be uploaded in full resolution.

I have added Stopwatch object to track execution time, CopyToAsync(ms) is consuming 99% of the execution. to give you an idea: to decrypt 9.6MB file it takes 16.10 seconds. and 16 seconds just for that line!!

Here is the decryption function:

```
public async Task<byte[]> Decrypt(IEncryptionPackage encryptionPackage)
{
    MemoryStream ciphertextBlob = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String((encryptionPackage.EncryptedKey)));

    byte[] key = key.Plaintext.ToArray();
    Stream data = encryptionPackage.CipherStream;

    SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = null;
    if (_algorithm == EncryptionAlgorithm.TripleDES)
        algorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    else if (_algorithm == EncryptionAlgorithm.AES)
        algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();
    else
        throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected algorithm type!");

    algorithm.Mode = _cipherMode;
    algorithm.Padding = _paddingMode;

    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, _salt, 100);
    algorithm.Key = rfc.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize / 8);
    algorithm.IV = rfc.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize / 8);

    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor();

        using (ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(data, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                   var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

                await cryptoStream.CopyToAsync(ms); // this line consume 99% of the execution time

        var  elapsedMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Number of secounds  to execute CopyToAsync:{0} seconds", elapsedMs));
            }
        }
        return ms.ToByteArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        algorithm.Clear();
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to decrypt than the above function?

Comment: Why are you decrypting photos at all? It seems like you should be decompressing them instead.

Comment: @DavidL I'm using end-to-end encryption.

Comment: Check memory usage in task manager and see if you have a memory issue or if something else is running at same time.

Comment: @jdweng thats's not the case, the "CopyToAsync()" function and the decryption process takes time.

Comment: Is it possible that `encryptionPackage.CipherStream` is what is taking a while? Try reading the stream into memory first and then decrypting; that will let you know whether it's some I/O or the actual decryption which is slow.

Comment: @StephenCleary encryptionPackage.CipherStream is stream result from AWS S3 response. I added Stopwatch object to track execution time. basically CopyToAsync() is the main line that taking 99% of the execution. To decrypt 9.6MB file it takes 16 sec.

Comment: So, from that it sounds like the S3 download is what's slow, not the decryption.

Comment: @StephenCleary No, apologies if I wasn't clear. there's no problem downloading the file from S3, it doesn't take much time. encryptionPackage.CipherStream is already filled with the data and passed to this function. As I mentioned earlier I have placed stopwatch object to track the execution time and it's basically in that line "cryptoStream.CopyToAsync(ms);"

Comment: Well, you say `encryptionPackage.CipherStream` is already filled with the data and maybe it is, but it's a `Stream`, not a `byte[]`, and I would not expect it to be filled with the data (MemoryStreams are the exceptions to this). So how do you know it's already filled with data?

Comment: Can you, just as a test, first read that 'data' into a byte[] and start the decryption from there? It will use more memory but clarifies where time is lost